# SAS - convert these UTM values to latitude and longitude

Tags: sas

I have large no. of data which have below columns. I want to convert these `UTM` values to `latitude and longitude` but I have done UTM zone data.

```
Cust id, UTM Easting,UTM Northing  
001,383737.26,6675682.46
```

Comment: How do you expect to do this without the zone?

Comment: Do you mean you don't have the UTM Zone data? Is it because it varies, or can you assume it's fixed through out your data?